# Unable to execute PHP shell

Tags: web-application, php, shellcode, backdoor

I have uploaded a simple PHP shell onto a server, but I get one of the following error messages when I am trying to execute a code:

> Warning: shell_exec() Unable to execute 'ls' in .... on line 2

> Warning: shell_exec() Unable to fork [ls] in ... on line

I think that there are some folder privileges that does not allow me to execute my code. How can I evade it?

Since that "open_basedir restriction in effect", is there a way to execute my shell?

Comment: Sounds like PHP is running under SElinux / AppArmor, which is preventing non-whitelisted forks from the Apache or PHP process.

Comment: Is there a way to evade it?

Comment: Unlikely, without access to the configuration information on the server.

Comment: @Polynomial, you could post that as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @Polynomial but, for example if I upload successful phpinfo() , I can get the information. Is it?

Comment: @Manuel Chances are you'll be able to read a lot of information, but file access may well be blocked, and you probably won't be able to fork processes at all.

Comment: On whos server you uploaded shell?

Comment: @mirsad on Windows IIS 7.5 - Php version 5.4.13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP function `shell_exec` calls the `fork` system call to create a new process for `ls`. It seems that the call to `fork` is blocked by some security policy.

You can still execute any PHP code that doesn't use blocked system calls. So even though you can not run `ls`, you can still obtain a file listing by running something like this:

```
<?php
    print_r(glob('*'));
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! For example, if I wanna see files and directories in a specified path, eg: C:\inetpub\sitesdata\ 
I need to use scandir, so it will be:
' <?php
$dir    = 'C:\inetpub\sitesdata\';
print_r(scandir($dir));
?>'

Comment: Just tried, and not works because "open_basedir restriction in effect"

Comment: @Sjoed , supposing that I've a file in: C:\testfolder\test\user\test.php , how can I read this file without call fork?